# Ubuntu touch emulator - no internet connection

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, emulation

I succesfully set up a touch emulator (x86 rc) and also enabled it as a kit to test apps.
However it is not connected to the network.
By connecting to the emulator with ssh, I can see it's network configuration:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29003 (29.0 KB)  TX bytes:8930 (8.9 KB)
          Interrupt:9 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9965 (9.9 KB)  TX bytes:9965 (9.9 KB)


phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I can ping the gateway but not the dns which is:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ more /etc/resolv.conf 
Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

Manually setting a working DNS does not solve the problem.
Is the host failing at providing the internet connection?
What is ubuntu-sdk using to provide internet connection to the virtual guest?

By manually starting the emulator with this command:

```
/usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator-x86 -memory 1024 -skindir /usr/share/ubuntu-emulator/skins -skin EDGE -sysdir /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386 -kernel /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/ubuntu-kernel -ramdisk /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/ramdisk.img -data /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/userdata.img -system /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/system.img -sdcard /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/sdcard.img -cache /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/cache.img -force-32bit -no-snapstorage -gpu on -scale 0.6 -no-jni -show-kernel -verbose -qemu
```

I end up with this:

```
emulator: autoconfig: -datadir /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386
emulator: Found target ABI=x86, architecture=x86
emulator: Found target API level: 19
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/gabriele/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/usr/share/ubuntu-emulator/skins/EDGE/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/userdata.img
emulator: WARNING: no Real SD Card found at '/home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/sdcardprime.img'
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1024MB

emulator: Found target ABI=x86
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.ramSize = 1024
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/sdcard.img
  hw.sdCardPrime = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  hw.bluetooth = yes
  kernel.path = /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/ubuntu-kernel
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = <build>
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-show-kernel"
emulator: argv[02] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[03] = "/home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator-x86 -show-kernel -android-hw /home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=/home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-gabriele/emulator-XgcEaA
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/userdata.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/gabriele/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/rc-386/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: KVM mode auto-enabled!
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.ifrename=eth1:rmnet0 android.ifrename=eth2:rmnet1 android.ifrename=eth3:rmnet2 android.ifrename=eth4:rmnet3 android.ifrename=eth5:wlan0 android.bluetooth=ttyS2 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit ndns=2
emulator:     trying to find: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/../usr/share/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/../usr/share/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

serial0 console
emulator: Found ro.adb.qemud build property: 1
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /usr/share/android/emulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ddms
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:167: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.4.0-4-goldfish (buildd@brownie) (gcc version 4.7.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu2) ) #1-Ubuntu PREEMPT Tue Jul 14 16:14:07 UTC 2015
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   NSC Geode by NSC
[    0.000000]   Cyrix CyrixInstead
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   Transmeta GenuineTMx86
[    0.000000]   Transmeta TransmetaCPU
[    0.000000]   UMC UMC UMC UMC
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009f000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000e8000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000003fff0000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000003fff0000 - 0000000040000000 (ACPI data)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fffc0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000] Notice: NX (Execute Disable) protection missing in CPU!
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.4 present.
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x3fff0 max_arch_pfn = 0x100000
[    0.000000] Warning only 895MB will be used.
[    0.000000] Use a HIGHMEM enabled kernel.
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-0000000037fe1000
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: 3fac5000 - 3fff0000
[    0.000000] Allocated new RAMDISK: 37ab6000 - 37fe0e3f
[    0.000000] Move RAMDISK from 000000003fac5000 - 000000003ffefe3e to 37ab6000 - 37fe0e3e
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: A valid RSDP was not found (20120320/tbxfroot-219)
[    0.000000] 895MB LOWMEM available.
[    0.000000]   mapped low ram: 0 - 37fe1000
[    0.000000]   low ram: 0 - 37fe1000
[    0.000000] Zone PFN ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      0x00000010 -> 0x00001000
[    0.000000]   Normal   0x00001000 -> 0x00037fe1
[    0.000000] Movable zone start PFN for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory PFN ranges
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000010 -> 0x0000009f
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000100 -> 0x0003fff0
[    0.000000] SFI: Simple Firmware Interface v0.81 http://simplefirmware.org
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000e8000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000e8000 - 0000000000100000
[    0.000000] Allocating PCI resources starting at 40000000 (gap: 40000000:bffc0000)
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 227440
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.ifrename=eth1:rmnet0 android.ifrename=eth2:rmnet1 android.ifrename=eth3:rmnet2 android.ifrename=eth4:rmnet3 android.ifrename=eth5:wlan0 android.bluetooth=ttyS2 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit ndns=2
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Initializing CPU#0
[    0.000000] Memory: 892448k/917380k available (5658k kernel code, 24480k reserved, 3257k data, 376k init, 0k highmem)
[    0.000000] virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfffe3000 - 0xfffff000   ( 112 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xf87e1000 - 0xfffe1000   ( 120 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf7fe1000   ( 895 MB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0ab6000 - 0xc0b14000   ( 376 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0786ac9 - 0xc0ab50c0   (3257 kB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0200000 - 0xc0786ac9   (5658 kB)
[    0.000000] Checking if this processor honours the WP bit even in supervisor mode...Ok.
[    0.000000] SLUB: Genslabs=15, HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
[    0.000000] Fast TSC calibration failed
[    0.000000] TSC: Unable to calibrate against PIT
[    0.000000] TSC: No reference (HPET/PMTIMER) available
[    0.000000] Marking TSC unstable due to could not calculate TSC khz
[    0.020000] Calibrating delay loop... 2138.11 BogoMIPS (lpj=10690560)
[    0.070000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.070000] Security Framework initialized
[    0.070000] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.070000] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.070000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[    0.070000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.070000] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.070000] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.070000] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.070000] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.070000] CPU: Intel Pentium II (Klamath) stepping 03
[    0.070000] Performance Events: Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only.
[    0.070000] NMI watchdog: disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
[    0.070000] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.070000] EVM: security.selinux
[    0.070000] EVM: security.SMACK64
[    0.070000] EVM: security.capability
[    0.070000] dummy: 
[    0.070000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.070000] PCI: PCI BIOS revision 2.10 entry at 0xfb3c0, last bus=0
[    0.070000] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.070000] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.070000] ACPI: Interpreter disabled.
[    0.070000] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.070000] i2c-core: driver [tps65090] using legacy suspend method
[    0.070000] i2c-core: driver [tps65090] using legacy resume method
[    0.070000] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.070000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.070000] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.070000] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.080000] PCI: Probing PCI hardware
[    0.080000] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.080000] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
[    0.080000] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x00000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.080000] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX/ICH IRQ router [8086:7000]
[    0.080000] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    0.080000] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.080000] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.080000] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.080000] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.080000] Switching to clocksource pit
[    0.082878] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.082878] pnp: PnP ACPI: disabled
[    0.082878] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.082878] IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.082878] TCP established hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    0.082878] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.082878] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 131072 bind 65536)
[    0.082878] TCP: reno registered
[    0.082878] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.082878] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.082878] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.082878] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    0.082878] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[    0.082878] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    0.082878] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.402560] Freeing initrd memory: 5292k freed
[    0.402560] platform rtc_cmos: registered platform RTC device (no PNP device found)
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_device_bus at ff001000 irq 4
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-battery at ff010000 irq 5
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_rfkill at ff011000 irq 6
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_memlog at ff012000 irq -1
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_nand at ff013000 irq -1
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev qemu_pipe at ff014000 irq 7
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_mmc at ff005000 irq 8
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff016000 irq 9
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff017000 irq 9
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff018000 irq 9
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff019000 irq 9
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_fb at ff01a000 irq 10
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_events at ff01b000 irq 3
[    0.402560] goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_audio at ff004000 irq 11
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_device_bus
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-battery
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_rfkill
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_memlog
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_nand
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered qemu_pipe
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_mmc
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_fb
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_events
[    0.402560] goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_audio
[    0.402560] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.402560] type=2000 audit(1459182311.400:1): initialized
[    0.482462] HugeTLB registered 4 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.482462] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.482462] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.482462] fuse init (API version 7.18)
[    0.482462] msgmni has been set to 1753
[    0.482462] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    0.482462] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.482462] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.482462] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.482462] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.482462] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.482462] goldfish_fb goldfish_fb.0: no framebuffer memblock
[    0.492494] allocating frame buffer 480 * 800, got f5800000
[    0.498764] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    0.506939] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.506939] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.506939] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    0.506939] [drm:i915_init] *ERROR* drm/i915 can't work without intel_agp module!
[    0.506939] brd: module loaded
[    0.506939] loop: module loaded
[    0.506939] goldfish_audio_probe
[    0.506939] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.506939] goldfish nand dev0: size c800000, page 512, extra 0, erase 32768
[    0.512459] goldfish nand dev1: size c800000, page 512, extra 0, erase 32768
[    0.522520] goldfish nand dev2: size 4200000, page 512, extra 0, erase 32768
[    0.522520] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.522520] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    0.522520] ne2k-pci.c:v1.03 9/22/2003 D. Becker/P. Gortmaker
[    0.522520] ne2k-pci 0000:00:02.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 9
[    0.522520] ne2k-pci 0000:00:02.0: sharing IRQ 9 with 0000:00:06.0
[    0.532607] eth0: RealTek RTL-8029 found at 0xc000, IRQ 9, 52:54:00:12:34:56.
[    0.532607] ne2k-pci 0000:00:03.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 11
[    0.532607] eth1: RealTek RTL-8029 found at 0xc100, IRQ 11, 52:54:00:12:34:57.
[    0.532607] ne2k-pci 0000:00:04.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 9
[    0.532607] eth2: RealTek RTL-8029 found at 0xc200, IRQ 9, 52:54:00:12:34:58.
[    0.532607] ne2k-pci 0000:00:05.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 11
[    0.532607] eth3: RealTek RTL-8029 found at 0xc300, IRQ 11, 52:54:00:12:34:59.
[    0.532607] ne2k-pci 0000:00:06.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 9
[    0.532607] ne2k-pci 0000:00:06.0: sharing IRQ 9 with 0000:00:02.0
[    0.532607] eth4: RealTek RTL-8029 found at 0xc400, IRQ 9, 52:54:00:12:34:5a.
[    0.532607] eth5: RealTek RTL-8029 found at 0xc500, IRQ 11, 52:54:00:12:34:5b.
[    0.532607] e100: Intel(R) PRO/100 Network Driver, 3.5.24-k2-NAPI
[    0.532607] e100: Copyright(c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation
[    0.532607] e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
[    0.532607] e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
[    0.532607] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 1.9.5-k
[    0.532607] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
[    0.532607] sky2: driver version 1.30
[    0.532607] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.532607] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.532607] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.532607] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[    0.532607] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    0.532607] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.532607] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    0.532607] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    0.532607] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.532607] *** events probe ***
[    0.532607] events_probe() addr=0xf87fe000 irq=3
[    0.532607] events_probe() keymap=qwerty2
[    0.532607] input: qwerty2 as /devices/virtual/input/input0
[    0.542512] rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    0.542512] rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
[    0.542512] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.542512] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.542512] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.542512] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.542512] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    0.542512] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.542512] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.542512] ashmem: initialized
[    0.542512] logger: created 256K log 'log_main'
[    0.542512] logger: created 256K log 'log_events'
[    0.542512] logger: created 256K log 'log_radio'
[    0.542512] logger: created 256K log 'log_system'
[    0.542512] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
[    0.542512] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (14027 buckets, 56108 max)
[    0.542512] ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
[    0.542512] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    0.542512] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.542512] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.542512] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    0.542512] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.542512] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    0.542512] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.552430] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.552430] console [netcon0] enabled
[    0.552430] netconsole: network logging started
[    0.552430] Freeing unused kernel memory: 376k freed
[    0.552430] Write protecting the kernel text: 5660k
[    0.552430] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2804k
Loading, please wait...
[    0.592408] mmc0: new SDHC card at address e118
[    0.592408] mmcblk0: mmc0:e118 SU02G 4.00 GiB 
[    0.592408]  mmcblk0: unknown partition table
starting version 219
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
[    0.903080] initrd: checking filesystem integrity for the userdata partition
[    0.903080] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    0.914248] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.482204] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): 6 orphan inodes deleted
[    2.482204] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): recovery complete
[    2.512555] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    2.562570]  mmcblk0: unknown partition table
[    2.562570] initrd: checking filesystem for userdata took (including e2fsck) 2 seconds
[    2.562570] initrd: mounting /dev/mmcblk0
[    2.772178] EXT4-fs: Warning: mounting with data=journal disables delayed allocation and O_DIRECT support!
[    2.772178] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.782340] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.802225] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): mounted filesystem with journalled data mode. Opts: discard,data=journal
[    2.802225] initrd: boot mode: ubuntu
[    2.882459] EXT4-fs (loop0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.903686] EXT4-fs (loop0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.132831] EXT4-fs (loop0): recovery complete
[    3.132831] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.132831] initrd: mounting system.img (image developer mode)
[    3.202450] initrd: mounting device image as ro
[    3.372169] EXT4-fs (loop1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.392494] EXT4-fs (loop1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.412554] EXT4-fs (loop1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.422541] initrd: device is generic_x86
[    4.092340] initrd: checking fstab /root/var/lib/lxc/android/rootfs/fstab* for additional mount points
[    4.152271] initrd: checking mount label mtdblock2
[    4.152271] initrd: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 as /root/android//cache
mount: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 on /root/android//cache failed: Invalid argument
[    4.162809] initrd: mounting /root/var/lib/lxc/android/system.img as /root/android/system
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    5.803601] init: ureadahead-touch main process (316) terminated with status 5
[    8.492412] init: no-cpu-hotplug main process (448) terminated with status 1
[   12.133270] init: /dev/hw_random not found
[   12.133270] init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
[   12.212482] init: /dev/hw_random not found
[   12.362598] init: cannot find '/system/bin/ubuntuappmanager.disabled', disabling 'ubuntuappmanager'
[   12.435027] init: property 'sys.powerctl' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.powerctl}'
[   12.435027] init: powerctl: cannot expand '${sys.powerctl}'
[   12.435027] init: property 'sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}'
[   12.435027] init: cannot expand '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}' while writing to '/proc/sys/vm/extra_free_kbytes'
[   12.435027] init: cannot find '/sbin/adbd', disabling 'adbd'
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                    [ OK ] 
/lib/init/init-d-script: 12: /etc/rc2.d/S02whoopsie: -c: not found
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
 * Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...                                [   43.523393] systemd-logind[1210]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@32011.service
[   45.843478] systemd-logind[1210]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@0.service
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500


sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glTexParameterf:1786 error 0x500
```

Update:
Apps do have internet connections, I tried pushing an app which required a connection and it worked.
The browser still crashes and webapps also crash probably due to the fact that they use webviews, hence the browser
Whats odd is that apps are connected to the internet while accessing the emulator via ssh I got no access

Comment: If you're downvoting this question, please also comment and explain how the poster can improve their question.